# Determinar un número mínimo a una variable

Tags: python

Necesito hacer un programa con cálculos, en el que la variable tenga siempre un número mínimo por defecto, que si quiero que el número mínimo sea 2, que con la operación no me salga 1.
Por ejemplo:

```
numero_1 = int(input("Inserte el número 1:"))
numero_2 = int(input("Inserte el número 2:"))

numero_final = numero_1 - numero_2
print("El número final, es: {} ".format(numero_final))
```

Comment: quieres validar que en los inputs no sea introducido un número menor al mínimo o lo quieres validar en el resultado??

Comment: `resultado = max(2, numero_final)`

Comment: Si, @Christian esta es mí intención.

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe